# Unknown user on a custom mail server

Tags: debian, email, postfix, dovecot

I made a custom mail server with Postfix and Dovecot from this tutorial : https://www.tictech.info/post/mail_preparation but I have a problem.
I can send mails from my custom server to an Outlook address (for example) but from Outlook to my custom server I have a mail 'Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender‏' with this content :

```
This is the mail system at host vps307550.ovh.net.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

The mail system

<cyprienaubry@1day-online.fr>: unknown user: "cyprienaubry"
```

Do you know what is the problem ? Maybe is my DNS Zone misconfigured...

Comment: It does appear that your DNS is not configured as a domain receiving email.  However, it appears this may be a server in your LAN, in which case I may not be able to see the appropriate DNS records. Please review the email posting under http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years/1987#1987

Answer (score 1):

If **1day-online.fr** is your domain and your domain has **proper MX records** and your mail server is **vps307550.ovh.net** (you've verified all this right?) and the **message actually made it to your mail server** (it's not hard to check) then:

**Check your logs**, find the relevant error and post it in your question if you still can't figure it out.

If anything I pointed out is incorrect, then you know where to look also. Update your question with more info if you still need help.

**I checked** just now and your domain has no MX records so I suggest starting with adding at least one and pointing it to your mail server. See how that works out.